# How do I legally sell my home brew in the UK?

Tags: legal

I want to sell my home brew in the UK.

I just make it at my flat, so I'm guessing I don't need a premises license?

I sell it bottled and closed, so could I get away with simply having an "off-license"?

Anything else that is required?

Ultimately I want to be 100% legitimate.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about selling alcohol and licensing, which is not considered on-topic for this SE.  See https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more info.

Comment: Based on existing questions that have not been disallowed, I'd say this one should be allowed too.  It's a question that would come-up for many new homebrewers that might simply be looking for a way to offset the equipment costs and when they realize what a hassle it would be, they quickly move on.

Comment: Given the number of other questions about this, I would say it should be re-opened. Or at the worst marked as duplicate. [Related](http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/380/3925)

Comment: Given that existing questions are allowed, and they generally relate to selling in the USA, which has very different alcohol licensing laws, I think this question should be re-opened. Understanding the alocohol licensing laws of the UK, when it comes to home brew (as opposed to owning a bar etc.), is very difficult to understand. That is where the need for enquiry is...